# Highest long range wifi g/n connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, signal-strength

The IT shop at the shopping mall as a public wifi connection that I maybe connect to at my house almost 1 street near (really near) ...

My laptops could not find the connection but I expect that a high powered USB wifi adapter and a yagi antenna would do well, what I should check and do before I try this ?

Note: If you have a decent and cheap idea to do that, talk proudly about it !

Comment: This may just be bunkum but it would be cool if you could prove it either way while you're researching a solution   http://www.5min.com/Video/How-to-Boost-Your-Wi-Fi-Signal-6232739

Comment: Can't point to any specific ones, but I've read articles about some super-high gain antennae listening in to connections from over a mile away.  To actually talk on the network may be a different story.  But it still proves a good point:  When it comes to sniffing wireless traffic, it doesn't matter how low the signal is if Eve has a really good set of ears.